# Selenium: How to check for ANY text in an element

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to verify if there is text inside an element. If there is text inside this element I want it to gotolabel and if there isn't any text want to to continue on. How can i go about doing this?

I've tried to **verifyText | id=note | (i don't know how to make it search for ANY word)**

But I don't know how to make it search for ANY text and make it skip to a label once it does find a text.

**EDIT:** I changed `verifyText` with `verifyElementPresent | id=note |`. If the element is present that means that there is text.

Now I'm stuck again. How can i make a

`if | verifyElementPresent == true |`

`gotolabel | start |`

kind of statement possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the regex match with *?

Something like the following should work according to the [SeleniumIDE doc](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#regular-expression-patterns)

```
verifyText | id=note | *Text to match*
```

Comment: I'm trying a different method now. How can I make an if statement with the true/false result of a `verifyElementPresent`?

Comment: No I did not. I don't understand it and I have been stuck on this problem for a few hours so I tried a different way of solving it. I re read what you said but I still don't understand it :(

Comment: The asterisk allows you to exclude text before and text after. Such as if the sentence is **This is text to find** and you use \*text\* it should return true since it's a partial match with regular expression. See the link I provided to the answer for more option

Comment: Ahh okay I understand now. The thing now is how could I use the true/false from verifyText command to do an if statement like in the edit i made?

Comment: There is no easy way. For any deep programming and testing purpose Selenium WebDriver is best fit. Someone else already faced that problem. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275354/using-if-else-in-selenium-ide) answer.