# Can we test online board game using selenium, in which random number are generated?

Tags: selenium, testing

I want to test my online board game with the testing tool, in game there are four players, dice type button will present, on clicking a button random numbers will be generated. Can anyone please suggest me any tool for that type of testing? Or can we use selenium for same?
Your help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: If i'm not wrong on click of a button you need to capture the number generated in an element. If you are looking at Web based testing of your game, selenium can be used.

Comment: Thanks Siva, Kindly tell me can I use Selenium IDE? As per the number generated on button, players will need to move. I know it will be possible through Webdriver but wanted to know about Selenium IDE.

Comment: Can you please let me know what are the steps or the flow you are trying to automate. Based on that i can suggest you if IDE can be used or not.

Comment: I have a board game, upto four players can share the same board. The size of board is 100.
Each player uses one after the other the dice to go forward on the board. 
The player moves forward exactly the number of places the dice is showing. The dice is a button, generating random number range between 1 to 6. I need to complete automate this.

Comment: Now this calls for Moving the Position on the board based the number generated. I think IDE wont be of much you when the automation involves the Jumping statements. So i would suggest you to go with WebDriver

Comment: Beside selenium, Can you recommend any other testing tool for this?

Comment: QTP-If you have licence to it. CodedUI- If you have Visual Studio

Comment: Also please refer content in this. See if it has some thing you rare looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11275354/using-if-else-in-selenium-ide